# What does pubsubhubbub mean for a front-end developer?

Tags: ajax, frontend, websub

Google's introductory text to pubsubhubbub describes it as a server-to-server protocol.

Google's [video introduction](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) includes an example where a web page is updated very quickly when an entirely separate blog is edited. It is stated that AJAX is in use. (Correct me if I'm wrong but AJAX is only ever going to be a polling technique)

I get the impression that, with the use of pubsubhubbub, although servers might not have to poll each other (because subscribers also run servers hubs can POST to), browsers have to poll with AJAX in the usual way (or use Comet or websockets). Is this correct?

Am right in thinking that from the perspective of the front-end developer, nothing changes? No new techniques are required if pubsubhubbub is being used?

Comment: It seems to me about getting / syndicating content. Possibly decreases load due to over-polling for new content. As a front-end dev, I doubt it would be of interest, although if you query 3rd party feeds somewhere, you could more safely cache a result locally (=on your server), possibly winning some speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> browsers have to poll with AJAX in the usual way (or use Comet or websockets). Is this >correct?

Yes, I believe it has no effect on the browser end of things.

> Am right in thinking that from the perspective of the front-end developer, nothing changes?

I think you are!